# Graph memory implementation

Tags: c++, graph

The two ways commonly used to represent a graph in memory are to use either an adjacency list or and adjacency matrix.  An adjacency list is implemented using an array of pointers to linked lists.  Is there any reason that that is faster than using a vector of vectors?  I feel like it should make searching and traversals faster because backtracking would be a lot simpler.

Comment: You would be backtracking only 1 at a time right? So doubly linked list would be as good?

Comment: But that would still require extra pointers.  So in terms of memory and speed would a vector still be better?

Comment: Usually it depends whether your graph is sparse or dense.

Comment: @KerrekSB Yeah, I was thinking about that and that is even not necessarily true at this point. I would use a hash+vector or hash+hash combo by the way for fast access.

Comment: If you have millions of vertices and only a handful of edges, then the memory non-locality of an adjacency matrix will just not be worth it... it really depends. Best to make your system modular so you can test both implementations and compare.

Answer (score 1):

The vector of linked adjacencies is a favorite textbook meme with many variations in practice.  Certainly you can use vectors of vectors.  What are the differences?

One is that links (double ones anyway) allow edges to be easily added and deleted in constant time. This obviously is important only when the edge set shrinks as well as grows.  With vectors for edges, any individual operation may require O(k) where k is the incident edge count.

NB:  If the *order* of edges in adjacency lists is unimportant for your application, you can easily get O(1) deletions with vectors.  Just copy the last element to the position of the one to be deleted, then delete the last!  Alas, there are many cases (e.g. where you're worried about embedding in the plane) when order of adjacencies is important.

Even if order must be maintained, you can arrange for copying costs to amortize to an average that is O(1) per operation over many operations.  Still in some applications this is not good enough, and it requires "deleted" marks (a reserved vertex number suffices) with compaction performed only when the number of marked deletions is a fixed fraction of the vector.  The code is tedious and checking for deleted nodes in all operations adds overhead.

Another difference is overhead space.  Adjacency list nodes are quite small: Just a node number.  Double links may require 4 times the space of the number itself (if the number is 32 bits and both pointers are 64).  For a very large graph, a space overhead of 400% is not so good.

Finally, linked data structures that are frequently edited over a long period may easily lead to highly non-contiguous memory accesses. This decreases cache performance compared to linear access through vectors.  So here the vector wins.

In most applications, the difference is not worth worrying about.  Then again, huge graphs are the way of the modern world.

As others have said, it's a good idea to use a generalized List container for the adjacencies, one that may be quickly implemented either with linked nodes or vectors of nodes.  E.g. in Java, you'd use `List` and implement/profile with both `LinkedList` and `ArrayList` to see which works best for your application.  NB `ArrayList` compacts the array on every `remove`. There is no amortization as described above, although `add`s *are* amortized.

There are other variations: Suppose you have a very dense graph, where there's a frequent need to search all edges incident to a given node for one with a certain label.  Then you want *maps* for the adjacencies, where the keys are edge labels.  Of course the maps can be hashes or trees or skiplists or whatever you like.

The list goes on.  How to implement for efficient *vertex* deletion?  As you might expect, there are alternatives here, too, each with advantages and disadvantages.